# Why doesn't my Whatsapp group show in my contacts?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I am new to Whatsapp Messenger.

I have contacts in my address book.

I have been added as a member into a GROUP, why doesn't the group appear in my contacts please the same as my contacts do?
Many thanks

Comment: Check this link for more info :https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21073373

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp does not have an option to display the group in the contacts list.

Whatsapp has the feature to show in which group does the contact is under his profile(and common with you and the contact)

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp does not have a separate pane to show the groups however if you want to see all your groups listed just like contacts, just select a message from any chat then go to "Forward" option. There you will see a separate pane for groups where you can find all your groups listed just like your contacts.

Comment: Is this still relevant for new updates?

Comment: Yes it is. There is still no standalone view for groups and this workaround is perfectly valid

Comment: I couldn't find this, is this removed in the new version?